# I am using an unrestricted api key for Google Maps SDK for iOS with my iOS Xcode project after having created a new key and deleting the old key

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directions-api

I am using an unrestricted api key for Google Maps SDK for iOS with my iOS Xcode project after having created a new key and deleting the old key, but my request is denied. It worked before when I used the first key.

Here is the error message:

> [error_message: This API project is not authorized to use this API., status: REQUEST_DENIED, routes: <__NSArrayM 0x60000097f5d0>(
>
> )

Here is my code in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("***")
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("***")

}
```

Here is my code where I run the request:

```
let directionsURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=1%20Cuntry%20Club%20Ln,%20Texarkana,%20AR&destination=1%20Cuntry%20Club%20Ln,%20Texarkana,%20AR&waypoints=optimize:true%7C921%20Orleans%20St,%20Texarkana,%20AR%7C2510%20E.%2011th%20St.,%20Texarkana,%20AR%2071846%7C4125%20Lynn%20Dr,%20Texarkana,%20TX%7C6002%20Yorktown%20Pl,%20Texarkana,%20TX%7C7007%20Stonewall%20Dr,%20Texarkana,%20TX%7C4009%20Constitution%20Dr,%20Texarkana,%20TX%7C413%20Dundee%20Rd,%20Texarkana,%20AR%7C2219%20Hazel%20St,%20Texarkana,%20TX%7C414%20Central%20Ave,%20Wake%20Village,%20TX&mode=driving&key=***"

let directionsURL = URL(string: directionsURLString)!

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
    do {
        
        let directionsData = try Data(contentsOf: directionsURL)
        
        let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: directionsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
        
        print(dictionary)
        
        let status = dictionary["status" as NSObject] as! String
        
        print("status=" + status)
        
    } catch {
        
        print(error)
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API key is indeed completely unrestricted, then this REQUEST_DENIED error you're getting can mean the following:

A) There's an issue with the billing account linked to your project, or you have not [created](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#create-billing-account) one. Please double check your billing account is enabled and in good standing.

B) The Directions API is disabled on your project. To enable it please check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk).

Hope this helps!